# Adding .NET 5.0 in 2022 windows Plesk VPS

Tags: .net, windows, vps, plesk

I am trying to change my Plesk Obsidian 18.0.55 VPS to be able to run .NET 5.0 or above but the only option is 4.8. How can I be able to get 5.0 or the latest version of .NET in my VPS?

[Dropdown of my .NET version options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFFjt.png)

I downloaded .NET Toolkit and it says other versions are installed however it won't let me choose them in the settings. [versions in .NET Toolkit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6GpN.png)

Comment: that option looks like for .net framework, not .net core/modern .net

Comment: How can I get asp.net 5.0 on the box?

Comment: The latest .NET version is 4.8.1. There is no 5.x. You probably mean something different like .NET Core, but the screenshot shows .NET.